# How does JavaScript evaluate if statement expressions?

Tags: javascript

I always thought that JavaScript's `if` statements did some kind of casting magic to their arguments, but I'm a little wary of what's actually going on behind the scenes.

I recently found a [JavaScript comparison table](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) and noticed that even though `-1 == true` evaluates to `false`, `if(-1){...}` will execute.

So within JavaScripts `if` statements, what happens to the expression? It seems reasonable to assume that it uses `!!{expression}` to cast it to an inverse boolean, then invert it again, but if that's the case, how does JS decide whether an object's inverse boolean representation is truthy or not?

Comment: I don't understand -- `-1` is truthy, so it will execute. (truthy != true)

Comment: there is a difference between something being "truthy" and something being (boolean) true value

Comment: e.g. `var x = true;` is both truthy and boolean `true`. But `var x = 'true';` is truthy but `'true'!=true` because `'true'` is a string type value and `true` is a boolean type value

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf
11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm
7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is wonky.

Yes, `-1 == true` results in false, but that's not what the if statement is doing.  It's checking to see if the statement is 'truthy', or converts to true.  In JavaScript, that's the equivalent of `!!-1`, which *does* result in true (all numbers other than zero are truthy).

## Why?!?

[The spec defines](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) the double equals operator to do the following when presented with a number and a boolean:

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

[ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) will convert the boolean `true` into the number `1`, so you're comparing:

```
-1 == 1
```

which anyone can tell you is clearly false.

On the other hand, an `if` statement is calling [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which considers any non-zero, non-NaN number to be `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Any JavaScript developer really needs to look at the documentation -- for this case, located here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2

9.2 ToBoolean

The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:

- **Argument** Type Result
- **Undefined** false
- **Null** false
- **Boolean** The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
- **Number** The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
- **String** The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
- **Object** true

(Sorry about the formatting, can't make a table here.)

Comment: Is this what is used behind the scenes, so to speak, when JavaScript converts an `if` statement's expression to a boolean? I'd imagine `!!{expression}` would be ever-so-slightly faster.

Comment: @DesertIvy `!` covertly calls ToBoolean: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9

Comment: @DesertIvy Yes, this is what happens behind the scenes.  And no, `!!` wouldn't be any faster because this ToBoolean would still have to be called on the first `!`, then again on the second.

Answer (score 1):

From [JavaScript The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)

The following values convert to, and therefore work like, `false`:

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`
- `-0`
- `NaN`
- `""`  // the empty string

All other values, including all objects (and arrays) convert to, and work like, `true`. `false`, and the six values that convert to it, are sometimes called *falsy* values, and all other values are called *truthy*.

Answer (score 1):

These things by themselves are falsy (or evaluate to false):

- undefined
- null
- 0
- '' or ""
- false
- NaN

Everything else i truthy.

Truthy-ness or falsy-ness is used when evaluating a condition where the outcome is expected to be either truthy (true) or falsy (false).

In your example `if(-1 == true)`, you are comparing apples and oranges. The compare is evaluated first (and resulted in false), and the results of that is used in your condition. The concept of truthyness/falsyness isn't applied to the operands the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

When if  state using with comparing variable different type js use .toString и .valueOf ( for more information check http://javascript.info/tutorial/object-conversion ) - just keep this in mind - it make so example much more easy to understand